# Fold the [card] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[card](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/card) does not look like it helps anyone (except the Texas Hold'em players). It doesn't make certain questions easier to find, and has low usage. I recommend getting rid of it.